# Grails: invalid access of stack red zone

Tags: java, macos, grails, jvm, red-zone

I am running a Grails 2.0.4 app on OS X (10.7.4). The app starts without any trouble, but when I try to access the home page in a browser, I get stack red zone errors:

```
Invalid access of stack red zone 0x1139b10c0 rip=0x112e50b70
Bus error: 10
```

and the server shuts down.

The app uses these plugins:

- code-coverage (1.2.5)
- codenarc (0.17)
- hibernate (2.0.4)
- jquery (1.7.1)
- mail (1.0)
- plugin-config (0.1.5)
- quartz2 (0.2.2)
- recaptcha (0.5.2)
- ref-code (0.3.0)
- resources (1.1.5)
- springcache (1.3.1)
- svn (1.0.1)
- tomcat (2.0.4)
- webxml (1.4.1), and
- yui-minify-resources (0.1.5)

Does anyone happen to have any tips, Grailswise, on how to get around this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few hits out there for this error ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501770/invalid-access-of-stack-red-zone-from-java-vm) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560889/invalid-memory-access-of-location-in-java) for example).  Mostly they revolve around serializing JSON objects creating a stack overflow error that wasn't reported as a stack overflow.  If you are doing anything like that it might be a good place to start.  Check any string you are serializing to make sure they are valid JSON:

```
JSONArray.fromObject(jsonString)
```

Another suggested bumping up the Java stack size (`-Xss1024k`).  If your JSON string looks ok, or you are not doing anything related to JSON,  you might try this to see if it is just a space issue.

Comment: It doesn’t seem to be a space issue (having tried to increase stack space, I don’t get the server to stay up). I will have to do some digging regarding your first suggestion, though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did that error produce a core dump? If yes google up for a core dump analyzer. Here are some good pointers on core dumo tools [Tool for analyzing java core dump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951095/tool-for-analyzing-java-core-dump)